# C++ Incorrect mouse movements

Tags: c++, winapi, mousemove

I write a basic mouse movement code. I set cursor to move 50px left each time. But its move more than I set.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    POINT p;
    SetCursorPos(1920, 540);
    while (1) {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, -50, 0, 0, 0);
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        cout << p.x << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

I tried to rewrite it from scratch.

Output should be:

```
1870
1820
1770
1720
etc...
```

Comment: Try `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, p.x-50, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Most of the movements are 113px, are you using a high-DPI monitor with a scaling that is not 100%? If so, is your app marked as DPI-aware? If not, then Windows is going to virtualize the coordinates you use, which could explain the difference.  In any case, you shouldn't be using `moue_event()` at all, as it has been deprecated and superceded by `SendInput()`, use that instead.

Comment: _"Relative mouse motion is subject to the settings for mouse speed and acceleration level."_

Comment: @Irelia when using `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`, the coordinates are not direct screen coordinates, they have to be *normalized* first: "*If `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` value is specified, **`dx` and `dy` contain normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535**. The event procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface, (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner.*"

Comment: i closed "Enhance pointer precision" from mouse settings and works. i'll try "SendInput()"

Comment: Looks like the monitor on your machine runs at 225%.  Declare your app to be dpiAware, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process